# Десериализация JSON ответа

Tags: java, json, gson, десериализация

Пытаюсь десериализовать JSON ответ с помощью GSON через
 `response ResponseFio = gson.fromJson(json, response.class)`, выпадает ошибка:

> Expected `BEGIN_ARRAY` but was `BEGIN_OBJECT`

Через `JsonParser` все получается, но через класс нет, подозрение на неправильный тип данных в классе

**JSON:**

```
{
"response": {
"count": 3,
"items": [
  {
    "id": 100,
    "first_name": "Иван",
    "last_name": "Иванов"
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "first_name": "Иван",
    "last_name": "Петров"
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "first_name": "Алла",
    "last_name": "Петрова"
  }
 ]
}
}
```

**Класс response:**

```
public class response {

List<GetFIO> response = null;

public response(){

}

public response(List<GetFIO> response){
    this.response = response;
}

public List<GetFIO> GetFriend(){
    return response;}
}
```

**Класс GetFIO:**

```
public class GetFIO {
int count = 0;
List<items> items = null;

public GetFIO(){

}

public GetFIO(int count, List<items> items){
    this.count = count;
    this.items = items;
}

public List<items> getItems() {
    return items;
}
}
```

**Класс items:**

```
public class items {
int id = 0;
String first_name = "",
        last_name = "";

public items(){

}

public items(int id, String first_name, String last_name){
    this.id = id;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}
}
```

Comment: `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`- у вас десериализатор ожидает массив, а получает объект. `List<GetFIO> response = null;` у класса `response`.

Comment: А пробовали изучить `jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.JSONParser;` и смотреть примеры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять тип на

```
GetFIO response = null;
```

т.е. когда вы десериализуете, то у вас `"response"` является объектом в json, а не массивом.